# How to use whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo() for different field and startAt() endAt() for different field at the same time

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter my user collection based on `timeIn` and `fullName`. For example, I want to get all users that have `timeIn >= today` and search the name of a user using `startAt`, `endAt`.

This is what I did but it's not working:

```
private void load() {
    Query query = db.collection("Monitoring");

    if(!course.isEmpty()){
        query = query.whereEqualTo("course", course);
    }

    if(!year.isEmpty()){
        query = query.whereEqualTo("year", year);
    }

    if(!block.isEmpty()){
        query = query.whereEqualTo("block", block);
    }

    query = query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("timeIn", 1671298034).orderBy("timeIn");

    if(selectedToDate != null){
        query = query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("timeIn", selectedToDate);
    }

    if(!search.isEmpty()){
        query = query.orderBy("fullName").startAt(search).endAt(search + '\uf8ff');
    }

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Monitoring> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Monitoring>()
            .setQuery(query, Monitoring.class)
            .build();

    Listener listener = new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void setTotal(int total) {
            if(total > 0){
                tv_noresult.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                tv_noresult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            tv_total.setText(String.valueOf(total));
        }
    };

    attendanceAdapter = new AttendanceAdapter(options, getContext(), listener);
    rv.setAdapter(attendanceAdapter);
    attendanceAdapter.startListening();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Firestore documentation on [query limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_limitations):

> In a compound query, range (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) and not equals (`!=`, `not-in`) comparisons must all filter on the same field.

Since `startAt` and `endAt` are jut aliases of `>=` and `<=`, those are also part of this limit.

So you won't be able to filter for `>=` on `timeIn` *and* search the `name` using `startAt`/`endAt`. You can only perform range conditions on one of them, and will have to perform further filtering in your application code.

If you want to learn more on why this limit exists, check out episode 2 of [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) on [How do queries work in Cloud Firestore?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=2&t=5s) I also gave an introduction to this in a talk a few years ago on [Querying Firebase and Firestore](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q).